# How reduce an array values from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, react-native

I want to reduce the array with regular pictures from the array with the Decoy pictures. What would be the right way to do that?

My code:

Array with regular pictures:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: width, flexWrap: 'wrap', height: photoWidth*2}}>
                {
                    this.state.photos.map((p, i) => {
                        return (
                            <SelectedPhoto
                                key={i}
                                index={i}
                                style={{
                                    width: photoWidth,
                                    height: photoWidth,

                                }}
                                limit={this.state.supportLength}
                                photo={p}
                                onSelectPhoto={this.onSelectPhoto}
                                onDeselectPhoto={this.onDeselectPhoto}
                            />
                        );
                    })
                }
                </View>
```

Array with decoy pictures:

```
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row', width: width, flexWrap: 'wrap', marginBottom:40}}>
                    {
                        this.state.decoyPhotos.map((p, i) => {
                            return (
                                <SelectedPhoto
                                    key={i}
                                    index={i}
                                    style={{
                                        width: photoWidth,
                                        height: photoWidth,
                                    }}
                                    limit={this.state.supportLength}
                                    photo={p}
                                    onSelectPhoto={this.onSelectPhoto}
                                    onDeselectPhoto={this.onDeselectPhoto}
                                />
                            );
                        })
                    }
                    </View>
```

I store my values is here:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.selectedDecoy=[];
    this.selectedPhotos = [];
    this.selectedPhotosIndex = 0;

    let photos = this.getSelectedPhotos();

    this.state = {
        decoyPhotos: null,
        photos: photos,
        loader: {
            loading: 1,
            message: "Loading photos..."
        },
        supportLength: photos.length,
        selectedDecoy: [],
        step: 0,
        progress: new Animated.Value(0),
        animationRunning: false
    };
```

I want to reduce the array with regular pictures from the array with the Decoy pictures. What would be the right way to do that?

Comment: What about [Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @HyyanAboFakher yes, i am trying to use this function, but I get syntax error. Can you please include an example that suits my code?

Answer (score 0):

Try it with the Array.prototype.reduce(). It's described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Here's an example by mozilla:

```
const array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

// 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer));
// expected output: 10

// 5 + 1 + 2 + 3 + 4
console.log(array1.reduce(reducer, 5));
// expected output: 15
```

Comment: I am aware of this function, but I cannot make it work with my syntax. Can you please include a code relevant to my syntax?